# When to use "the" in numbering and labelling?

Tags: definite-articles, zero-article

*Practical English Usage* 142.20 reads

> We usually leave out articles in abbreviated styles:

> **numbering and labelling**

> - Go through door A

- Control to Car 27: can you hear me?
- Turn to page 26.

What can be considered labels? For example, "on page 10" and "in Chapter 2" are clear. But do the following need "the"?

- The/Ø name 'John' is popular.
- We suggest you use the/Ø method Y...
- ...as the/Ø variable *x* grows...
- The/Ø words "evokeo cvec" do not mean anything.

[Ø = the null (or possibly the zero) article]

In other words, can "the" be omitted in every *noun + its label/name* phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** I have completely rewritten this answer, because what I wrote first (about the context), though accurate, was not in fact the answer to the question. Thank you for calling me on it, @homocomputeris.

This form without "the" is used only when the item is one of a set of [noun]s which are distinguished by the letter or number: the combination of [noun] and the label act as the name, but you couldn't (usually) use just the label without the noun.

So your "method" example would work, if there was a recognised list of methods referred to as X, Y, Z ... (either in the present document, or in the field at large).

It's possible that "variable *x*" might be used that way, but I'm not sure.

The "name" and "words" examples do not work, though.

Comment: Well, and if it is not an instruction: "I could not find his number in the phone book because the/_ page 15 hand been torn out"?

Comment: My apologies, @homocomputeris: my answer , though accurate, completely misses the point of your question. I will rewrite it.